# Remove semitransparent pixels on Smart Object in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, smartobject

I found [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/making-all-semi-transparent-pixels-fully-opaque/m-p/9314423) adobe community post and it's working great.

```
Summary of the adobe answer:
Layer > Layer Mask > From Transparency then edit the Layer Mask however necessary (Image > Adjustments > Threshold maybe).
```

But I have to do it everytime one by one.

Is there any smartfilter or effect that removes semi transparent pixels? So it can be applied to an smartobject and I don't have to make a new mask everytime the content of the smartobject changes?

If it's important: The content will have multiple colors. My testing with threshold (as a smartfilter) always reduced my colors to pure black.

Also I don't want to use an action, I know it would be possible with it, but because this will be shared with multiple co-workers, an action can lead to more errors than just a simple replacement of the smartobject content.

Here is an example, how an example image currently looks and how it looks after I did the steps mentioned above. Now I need something that would do this (if configured once) automatically.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

My photoshop file:
[Download my Photoshop file from mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/file/uwkelu29ismlkzj/Semitransparent_Pixels.psd.psd/file)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? You want some sort of "dynamic mask" which can detect semitransparent pixels when a smart object changes? (Please make the question self-contained so it isn't reliant on the Adobe forums to *try* and figure out what you are asking.)

Comment: Ok, I will improve the question.

Comment: Ahh... so you want to remove anti-aliasing... hmm... (thanks for editing `:)`)

Comment: More or less. The effect doesn't come from resizing. It's a combination of mosaic and a pattern overlay. But the final result should only have "same colored pixels" without transparency.

Comment: Can you add a multicolored PNG with transparency like the one you work with so we can use that to find a solution? I'm pretty sure it's possible, but I need an image to work with.

Comment: @Wolff Yes, I will prepare one. It will be a PSD, because (if it's not clear) I have vector graphics that I want to place in my smartobject and the result should be my second image. I will update the question asap

Comment: It's just that a PSD needs to be hosted on another site where a PNG can just be added. A smart object is handled like a merged image by Photoshop anyway. Smart filters don't really care about the layers inside the smart object.

Comment: Checked out the PSD. I understand the problem better now. It would be easier to make the graphics so the unwanted antialiasing don't get introduced instead of removing it afterwards. For example by drawing the image in the chunky resolution you want (24 times smaller) and with pencil tool to avoid antialiasing. Then make the drawing into a smart object and scale it up 24 times with nearest neighbor interpolation and add the pattern.

Comment: But if people paste in vector objects or draw with a soft brush inside the smart object, it won't work. Not easy to force smooth graphics to become pixel art automagically. What happens if people paste in a regular image? How should the colors be reduced? Do you see the dilemma?

Comment: Yeah, I see the problem there. But it will just be for simple vectors (most of the time logos). And it does't have to be 100% accurate. The final thing should simulate a stitched effect, so customers realize that their logo won't be 100% sharp like a vector. And of course the effect isn't that hard to recreate manually, or even my "end method" isn't that hard. It's just more vulnerable to errors with co-workers if they forget one step or something. Also, the "layout" will change sometimes multiple times a day. So a Smart Object would simplify and speed up a lot.

Comment: Actually threshold is nearly 99% what I'm looking for. The only problem is that it removes and distorts the colors...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130901/discussion-between-wolff-and-skarpeta).